# Divergence free is inherited under congruence?

Tags: divergence-operator

Let's define "Divergence" 
$$
\text{Div}A(x)=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{d}\frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial x_{j}}\right)_{1\leq i\leq d},
$$
where $A$ is a $d$ by $d$ matrix and $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$. I use
capital D, which distinguishes the original divergence.

Here's my question :

> Let's $B(y) := PA(P^{-1}y)P^{T}$. If $\text{Div}A(x)=0,$ then
>   $\text{Div}B(y)=0$ where $P\in\text{GL}_{d}(\mathbb{R})$.

---

My trial : $$\sum_{l}^{d}\sum_{i,j}^{d}p_{1i}\left(\sum_{k}^{d}\frac{\partial a_{ij}\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{k}}\tilde{p_{kl}}\right)p_{lj}$$
where $P^{-1}=\left(\tilde{p}_{ij}\right)$. (I'm not sure)

Comment: Recommend removing 'modular arithmetic' tag since has nothing to do with the question